# "Logically equivalent formulae express the same _______." <- What word do logicians use for the blank?

Tags: logic, terminology

*Meaning* denotes the truth conditions of a sentence: what would have to be the case for the interpreted formula to be true. Nevertheless, without an interpretation, two logically equivalent formulae express something that makes them equivalent. What is the name for that?

Comment: What about *extension*, i.e. the collection of things defined by the expressions ?

Comment: @TomCollinge Hm. Although, ~(P & Q) <-> (~P v ~Q). They have no extension, but are still logically equivalent.

Comment: I still think that *meaning* is the correct answer. To ask for "what formulae express [...] without an interpretation" looks to me as a sort of *contradictio in terminis*. Without interpretation, formulae express **nothing**.

Comment: @Hal The logical tradition would say that the extension of a sentential wff is its truth-value.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA You know your stuff. I expect I will defer to you in regards to matters of logic for some time, so I proffer this objection as a question: At the very least, *~(P & Q) <-> (~P v ~Q)* expresses the logical equivalency of two differently expressed formulas. That is something; is it not?

Comment: @Hal - I've tried to add some reflections in my answer. I've **no** certainity about meaning, but without it what is left ? You say that the equivalence between two formulas express "the logical equivalency of two differently expressed formulas". Frankly speaking, it seems to me a very poor ... something. :)

Comment: Two truth-functionally logically equivalent formulas (in say 2-valued logic) "$\alpha$" and "$\beta$" don't necessarily have the same deductive power even if we have C$\alpha$$\beta$ and C$\beta$$\alpha$ as theorems.  Suppose our only rules of inference are detachment and uniform substitution.  The formulas CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp, CCCpqrCCrpCsp, and CpCqp are all logically equivalent.  However, CpCqp cannot serve as a sole axiom of the implicational propositional calculus as CCCpqrCCrpCsp can.  And CCCpqrCCrpCsp is not a sole axiom of C-N classical logic as CCCCCpqCNrNsrtCCtpCsp is.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Fair enough. I could have phrased that more clearly: I meant -the symbols themselves- express the logical equivalence between the two concatenation of symbols - and they can do that without the logical terms being interpreted. Although, I agree - it is hardly something.

Comment: We could say that the two expressions are the same **assertion**. This works, even without an interpretation, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that this one is a "slippery" question.

We can approach it from different points of view, with increasing degree of "difficulty" and, so to say, "philosophical committment".

*First approach* : is it possible to avoid to be "involved with" *meaning* in the elucidation ?

Stay, for simplicity, with *propositional logic*; we have that :

> $\varphi \leftrightarrow \psi$ iff $\vdash \varphi \rightarrow \psi$ and $\vdash \psi \rightarrow \varphi$.

If we assume *modus ponens*, this amount to "interderivability", i.e. :

> $\varphi \vdash \psi$ and $\psi \vdash  \varphi$.

There is **no** "smell" of meaning here. But, without meaning, i.e. without interpretation of the above formulae, what is "expressed" by their equivalence ?

*Second approach* : there is a long tradition in modern logic regarding "extensionality". From Frege's *Begriffsschrift* onwards, mathematical logic has been concerned mainly with *truth-functional* contexts.

According to Frege, the *Bedeutung* of an entire proposition is its truth-value, either the True or the False. For Frge, complete propositions, like names, have objects as their *Bedeutungen*, and in particular, the truth-values the True or the False. In this way, he is able to transcribe sentential connectives such as “and” and “or,” etc., as truth functions in the strictest sense — functions that take truth-values as argument and yield truth-values as value. [see Kevin Klement, *Frege and the Logic of Sense and Reference* (2002)]

According to W&R [see Alfred North Whitehead & Bertrand Russell, *Principia Mathematica to 56* (2nd ed - 1927), page 115] :

> It is obvious that two propositions are equivalent when, and only when, both are true or both are false. Following Frege, we shall call the truthvalue of a proposition truth if it is true, and falsehood if it is false. Thus two propositions are equivalent when they have the same truth-value.

AIt should be observed that, if $p \equiv q$, $q$ may be substituted for $p$ without altering the truth-value of any function of $p$ which involves no primitive ideas except those enumerated in *1 [the truth-functional connectives].

> We shall give the name of a truth-function to a function $f(p)$ whose argument is a proposition, and whose truth-value depends only upon the truth-value of its argument. All the functions of propositions with which we shall be specially concerned will be truth-functions, i.e. we shall have
>
> > $p \equiv q . \supset .f(p) \equiv f(q)$.
>
> The reason of this is, that the functions of propositions with which we deal are all built up by means of the primitive ideas of *1. But it is not a universal characteristic of functions of propositions to be truth-functions. For example, "A believes $p$" may be true for one true value of $p$ and false for another.

In "modern" terms, this is the so-called **Replacement theorem** [see S.C.Kleene, *Introduction to Metamathematics* (1952), page 116] :

> If $A$ and $B$ are formulas, $C_A$ is a formula constructed from a specified occurnce of $A$ using only the [truth-functional connectives], and $C_B$ results from $C_A$ by replacing this occurrence of $A$ by $B$, then $A \leftrightarrow B \vdash C_A \leftrightarrow C_B$.

And equivalently : $A \leftrightarrow B, C_A \vdash C_B$.

In a "universe" of "extensional" contexts, that considered by the  "simplified" semantics of logical languages, it is easy to "equate" the condition for two equivalent formulae of having the same "truth conditions" with that of expressing "the same thing".

It is likely then, that "that thing" is their meaning.

*Third approach* : see [Michael Dummett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dummett) and his [The Logical Basis of Metaphysics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0674537866) (Harvard UP, 1991) and [Proof-Theoretic Semantics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/).

The basic idea - I think - is to build a theory of *meaning* without *truth*. But I'm not prepared to discuss it.

Answer (score 2):

I would still go for **meaning** here: The *meaning* of a formula is a function that takes a structure *and* a valuation for the formula's free variables, and produces a truth value.

Logically equivalent formulas have the same meaning in this sense.

Comment: What do you mean by *structure*? Isn't the formula the structure -or does it just represent the structure? In either case, the structure is implicit in the formula. Whereas the interpretation (Let B denote 'Burning' and h denote 'my house') and valuation (False, given the current state of affairs) are independent of the formula. Is that correct?

Comment: @Hal: A "structure" over a first-order language consists of a set that the quantifiers range over, plus interpretations for all of the non-logical symbols in the language. Sometimes the entire structure is known as an "interpretation" of the language.

Comment: I see. So the structure is the mapping of symbols to things in a language?

Comment: @Hal: Yes -- or in other words, it's the same as a "model", except it is not implied to satisfy any particular axioms.

Comment: This answer is in fact the same as mine: the "meaning" of two formulae is the same is the semantics of the formulae are the same on all structures (since two functions are equal when they agree on every input).

Comment: But what if we don't know anything about the semantics of the logical system?  What if we're just given a set of axioms and set of deductive rules?

Answer (score 0):

Logicians use the word **semantic** to refer to the "meaning" of a formula. It is the interpretation of the formula in a given structure.

For instance take the First-Order language with $+,*,0,Succ$ (the classic Peano language). For instance $\varphi(x)=(\exists y. y*y=x)$ is a formula in this language.
If we interpret $\varphi$ in the structure $(\mathbb N,+,*,0,Succ)$, then the semantic of $\varphi$ is the set of square numbers (the set of $x$ that makes $\varphi(x)$ true). But we can also interpret $\varphi$ in $(\{0,1\},\vee,\wedge,0,Succ)$ in which case its semantic is the set $\{0,1\}$. If a formula $\psi$ does not contain free variables, then its semantic is imply $true$ or $false$, and still can depend of the structure For instance the formula $\exists x,y,z: x\neq y\wedge x\neq z\wedge y\neq z$ states that the structure has at least $3$ elements, so it is true on $\mathbb N$ but false on $\{0,1\}$.

So the semantic of $\varphi$ depends on the structure on which it is interpreted. Two formulae are **logically equivalent** if they have the same semantic under **all** structures. It means that their equivalence is not an accident due to the chosen structure, but is "intrinsic" to the formulae: they express the same thing, regardless of what is the precise meaning of the operators.

Comment: I define interpretation as assigning meaning to place holders, (e.g. let P represent Tom Jones). Do you define it that way too?

Comment: yes exactly. I will precise the answer.

Comment: thank you, but I meant to ask what two logically equivalent, uninterpreted, formulae represent that makes them equivalent.

Comment: I hope the new answer clarifies it.

Comment: @Hal - But I think that we may call it *meaning*; **if** we accept the "simplified" *semantics* of logical languages, when we say that two equivalent formulae express "the same thing", I think that "that thing" is their meaning : they have the same "truth conditions". But there are alternatives : see [Michael Dummett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dummett) and [Proof-Theoretic Semantics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theoretic-semantics/)

Comment: "Logicians use the word semantic to refer to the "meaning" of a formula. It is the interpretation of the formula in a given structure." Eh? I have never, ever, come across this usage. Which logicians use this terminology and in which books?

Comment: Usually, a logical formalism comes with two sets of definition: "syntax" (what are the admissible formulae) and "semantics" (what formulae mean). It is done like this in every paper about formal logic.

Comment: Here is the relevant wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_semantics_(logic)

Comment: @Denis There exist papers which make no reference to semantics whatsoever: http://www.filozof.uni.lodz.pl/bulletin/pdf/32_3_6.pdf  (additionally one might point out that even if one did refer to a particular semantics like the {true, false} semantics of two-valued logic, the paper ends up showing that something holds for *any* logic which has those formulas as axioms or theorems no matter it's semantics).

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Indeed, some works (like the 4-page paper you found) are just interested in syntactical maninpulation of formulas, regardless of semantics. It can be interesting, but it is not hte majority of works on formal logic. Ok I should have replaced "every" by "most of" in my previous comment...

Comment: @Denis I think this question is looking for a perspective closer to the perspective of those papers.  In other words, I think it's asking us to define what logical equivalence means regardless of semantics.

Comment: Then the question is not precise enough, as it will depend on the particular logic, to know which set of rules can be used. Still, I think that thinking about "true in every structure" is a good way to think about "true regardless of semantic". More precisely, we can say that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent if the formula $\varphi\Leftrightarrow\psi$ is true in every structure.

Comment: @Denis The Wikipedia page you link to of course does talks about semantics, as logicians do,  not about "the semantic of $\varphi$" (a phrase seemingly of your own invention).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "think that "that thing" is their meaning : they have the same 'truth conditions'". - Well said.

Comment: @PeterSmith I didn't expect to encounter such an opposition to the concept of semantic of formulae. Here is an example (first google result): http://semantics.uchicago.edu/kennedy/classes/w11/sp2/handouts/predicatelogic.pdf
I happen to encounter this kind of semantics in my work in formal logic in many papers...

Comment: @Denis Talk of semantics, yes, of course. "The semantic of $\varphi$", no. It isn't either ordinary English or technical logicians' English.

Comment: @Denis But what if "⇔" is not a connective of the structure?  What if "⇔" is not definable for the structure?  For example, what would "equivalence" mean for the implicational calculus of propositions or the positive logic of propositions?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Yes the previous comment only holds if you can define $\Leftrightarrow$ (which is true as soon as you have for instance $\vee$ and $\neg$). Otherwise this trick can't be used, and we go back to the original answer that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ must behave the same on all structures.

Comment: @PeterSmith Why do you say it's not correct ? In the document I sent there is for instance a question "Exercise: determine the semantic values of the (well-formed) formulas in (3)". We usually use "semantic" as a short for "semantic value" that's all.

Comment: @Denis It doesn't matter in the broader scheme of things, but no, "we" don't usually use "semantic" as short for "semantic value", if "we" is supposed to mean logicians in general. If it is an idiosyncratic local usage in your neck of the woods, so be it.

Comment: @PeterSmith I can only speak for my community, which uses logic in the context of theoretical computer science (including temporal logic, first-order logic, monadic second-order logic,...), so the "we" applies at least for this community.

Comment: @Denis I guess have to take your word for it. But can you give me a reference or two to published compsci literature in quality journals where phrases of the form "the semantic of $\varphi$" as opposed to "the semantic value of $\varphi$" are habitually used? I've never come across  this linguistic quirk in the compsci literature I've encountered!

Comment: @PeterSmith Here are a few examples :
http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~colcombe/Publications/LICS10-colcombet-loeding-submitted.pdf
http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-328/paper12.pdf
http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/95/39/74/PDF/chevallet95b_miro95.pdf
http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~france/CS614/Slides/Ch5-Summary.pdf

Comment: @Denis Thanks. Interesting. Some are using "semantic" where "semantics" is the normal English of native speakers, and some seem, as you say, to be using "semantic" where "semantic value" would be expected. Both usages will strike  a native speaker as bad English (I asked around at coffee yesterday about this sort of thing, so it isn't just me!).

Comment: @PeterSmith ok thanks for the input then, I'll try to avoid this use in the future.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, two logically equivalent formulas express *interderivability*, or one could say that the formulas are *interderivable*.  In other words, in a given calculus with axioms, if **A** is logically equivalent to **B**, then if **A** gets assumed, then we can derive **B** using only the rules of inference and axioms of the calculus, and if we assume **B**, then we can derive **A** using only the rules of inference and axioms of the calculus.

So one might say that logically equivalent formulae express the same derivability.

For instance, in Lukasiewicz three-valued logic (p$\rightarrow$q) is equivalent with ($\lnot$q$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p) implying that if (p$\rightarrow$q) is interderivable with ($\lnot$q$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p) (note that this does NOT imply that [(p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$($\lnot$q$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p)] is a theorem NOR that [($\lnot$q$\rightarrow$$\lnot$p)$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$q)] is a theorem here (though in fact they are theorems here), since Lukasiewicz three-valued logic does not have a deduction theorem which allows for reasoning to those theorems in this way).

Interderivability in some ways comes as a more general notion than logical equivalence, since logical equivalence only applies to well-formed formulas.  In contradistinction, interderivability applies to sets of well-formed formulas under a fixed rule.  For example, the axiom set {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCNpNqCqp} under detachment and uniform substitution is interderivable with the axiom set {CCpqCCqrCpr, CpCNpq, CCNppp} under detachment and substitution.  But, the set {CpCqp, CCpCqrCCpqCpr, CCNpNqCqp} under detachment and substitution is not equivalent to {CCpqCCqrCpr, CpCNpq, CCNppp} under detachment and substitution since neither set with its rules is a well-formed formula.

Comment: What is the objection to this answer?  This answer doesn't refer to semantics or require an interpretation does it?